# for loop that has O(c^k) - exponential time complexity

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity

How to write a for loop that has O(c^k) - exponential time complexity?
I want to write a for loop that have a O(3^n)

Comment: You can see it as `c` being the number of elements and `n` being the number of nested levels. So if you loop over 10 items in a double nested loop you have 10^2 iterations in total.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one loop to do this

```
for(long i = 0; i < Math.power(c, k); i++)
```

or

```
for(long i = 0; i < Math.power(3, n); i++)
```

Comment: public void run(int n)
        {
            System.out.println(power(3, n));
        }

        public int power(int c, int n)
        {
            int result = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                result *= n;
            }
            return result;
        }

does this code give me a  O(c^k) - exponential time complexity?

Comment: @benjamintan - no it doesn't.

Comment: @benjamintan There is no `k` in your code.  If you meant `n = k` it still wouldn't be close to being right.